# search the contents of the module by using the dotnetnuke search tool in the dotnetnuke 9

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

How can I search the contents of the module by using the dotnetnuke search tool in the dotnetnuke 9, when we create a module. Please explain in code and database.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be Christoc's module development templates.  Basically, you have to create a Searchable interface, and the stubbed out modules show you you to do that.

Comment: Do not need to change the database؟

Comment: I don't think ISearchable is necessary/works anymore Joe, due to deprecation in 9.2

Answer (score 0):

There's a blog covering [ModuleSearchBase on DnnSoftware.com](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/154913/integrating-with-search-introducing-modulesearchbase) and also in [their wiki](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/modulesearchbase)

Essentially note that you only need to pass documents that have ***CHANGED*** or ***MODIFIED*** since the last time into the `GetModifiedSearchDocuments` override you write.

Have your controller inherit from `ModuleSearchBase` and create an override:

```
public override IList<SearchDocument> GetModifiedSearchDocuments(ModuleInfo    modInfo, DateTime beginDate)
{
    ...
    var searchDocuments = new List<SearchDocument>();
    ...
    searchDocuments.Add(searchDoc);
    ....
    return searchDocuments;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not need to change the database؟ i need a simple